# Lucene search terms with C#

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I implemented searching with Lucene as code below

```
  var fields = new[] { "Locality", "SubLocality", "Administrative_level_1", "Administrative_level_2", "Administrative_level_3" };    
               var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, fields, analyzer);             
               var query = queryParser.Parse(searchQuery);
               var hits = searcher.Search
                (query, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
                var results = _mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);
                analyzer.Close();
                searcher.Dispose();
                return results;
```

If i put the key word like "Eastern Cape",it is also displaying result for "Western Cape".

How can i only get result searching for "Eastern Cape"?

Comment: You don't show you actual searchQuery. You seem to want to search for a phrase. In that case your SearchQuery needs the be quoted with ""

Comment: Could you explain more about your solution?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up the possibility of using exact search, and that is done by creating a phrase query in your `queryBuilder` out of your `searchquerystring`.